# Partition in page into thirds vertically

Tags: wrap

I'd like to partition the page into thirds vertically. That means, the first part starts at the upper left corner of the text body (as usual), the second part starts at (0,-1/3*\textheight) [as seen from the upper left corner of the text body] and the third starts at (0,-2/3*\textheight). I tried `\begin{minipage}[t][0.33\textheight][t]{\textwidth}…\end{minipage}`, but it almost always breaks the layout in some way.

The minipages need to contain wrapped images. At the moment, I work with `wrapfig`.

Are there other ways to achieve the desired layout?

Comment: basically something like that should work, although you may need to take care of depth as well as height of the boxes. Please make a complete document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\def\a{One two three four five. Red green blue yellow black white. }
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\par\a a b c d e f g}
\def\c{\b\a\b\par}

\def\foo{%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{.7\linewidth}{2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}\c}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textheight][t]{\textwidth}\foo\end{minipage}
\par\nopagebreak\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textheight][t]{\textwidth}\foo\end{minipage}
\par\nopagebreak\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\textheight][t]{\textwidth}\foo\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```